# Why was $U=\frac{1}{2}QV$ not listed in my book as the potential energy of a capacitor?

Tags: charge, potential-energy, tensor-calculus, voltage, capacitance

$$U=\frac{Q^2}{2C}\tag{1}$$

$$U=\frac{1}{2}CV^2\tag{2}$$

$$U=\frac{1}{2}QV\tag{3}$$

$(1)$ and $(2)$ were listed in my book. However, I think $(3)$ is also a valid formula. Is there any particular reason why (3) was left out?

Comment: Unlike $P=IV$, which is true and fundamental, (3) just happens to be true for capacitors. It will be difficult to work with the variables Q and V at the same time, whereas typically C is a constant and you can immediately see the quadratic behaviour at a glance. So it is too rare for (3) to be useful, and thus will not be listed in any formula sheet, whereas there are good chances for (1) or (2) to be useful on a formula sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in your book somewhere for sure. Just maybe not in the section about capacitors because it's much more general than that.

In Griffith's "Introduction to Electrodynamics" it's equation 2.42 and 2.43 in the section "The Energy of a Point Charge Distribution"

$$
W=\frac{1}{2}\sum_i q_iV(r_i)
$$
$$
W=\frac{1}{2}\int\rho(\mathbf{x})V(\mathbf{x})d^3\mathbf{x}
$$
The work it takes to assemble point charges $q_i$ is given by the sum over those charges times the voltage at their position (but in the first formula you have to ignore the contribution of a charge to its own voltage, which is infinite). For a capacitor, you have a charge $Q$ which all sits on different spots on a conductor with voltage $V$.

The one half prevents double counting (including both the potential on charge 1 from charge 2 and the potential from charge 2 on charge 1).

Comment: Just be aware that in Section 27-4 and the foreshadowing in Chapter 8 of Volume 2 of Feynman lectures, he point out that this is only true for electrostatics and things are much more complicated in dynamics. https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_27.html